# Hide labels side panel in Gmail for tablet

Tags: gmail, tablet

I just want to **not** see labels on the left side bar in Gmail with a Google Nexus 7 tablet, just as on Android phones like Galaxy Nexus for instance.

In fact I want to use the whole width the screen for email summaries: titles and senders.

How can I get this view?